# How can I filter STDIN by globbing in bash?

Tags: bash, glob

My bash script get full paths via pipe (`stdin`) and get exclude patterns by command line arguments. Currently this handles regexp patterns, but I want to rewrite to handles [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) patterns only.

**How can I filter `stdin` with glob patterns (like `fnmatch`)?** Because as far as I know, I can't use `grep` for globbing, and I don't want to translate [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) patterns to regexp by hand. *- so I want to find a fast and not hacky solution.*

### Example:

```
echo -e 'apple tree\nbanana tree\norange tree' | ./filter_script.sh '*ban' '*ge*'
```

#### Expected output:

```
# banana tree
# orange tree
```

*Full example code is on [GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/andras-tim/6143769fa2afc83e253d19e0d30b6bd2)*

#### Edit 1:

In the real life, this script will get **thousands of paths**, so I think, the native bash implementations will be not good.

Anyone know "grep like" [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) filter?

Comment: What is your expected output for a given input? the example provided in the link is not helping

Comment: Instead of gists, why just doesn't add the question here with the expected output? It is much better because we can faster clearing problems with your question.

Comment: ... like, how for the sake of gods, the `*n*` means `apple tree`? (as in the your expected output)?!

Comment: Are you getting a string input as in the example (or) a file?

Comment: @jm666, you are right, sorry, I fixed the example on Gists

Comment: @Inian, doesn't matter, because I want to filter data via pipe

Comment: Please, define the `hacky`. IMHO to get non-hacky result you should convert the `glob` to `regex`. The got regex will be usable either in `grep` or any other program which understand regexes (plenty of), and you will end with `grep` as in your gist. The rules converting globs to regex aren't complicated and can be done using pure bash...

Comment: Ad: `Anyone know "grep like" glob filter?` - YES it is called `perl`. :)

Comment: The paths your script must handle, are they arbitrary paths, or do they have to match an actual file on the system (and may be discarded if they do not)?

Comment: I'm open any solution what I can call easily from a bash script. (e.g. `awk`)

Comment: @Fred the input path list is generated by `find`; but at processing of this I don't care about existence of paths, only matching.

Comment: @andras.tim Any reason why you do not perform the globbing with `find`?

Comment: @Fred I get paths from different subsystem, so I can't override this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming* you want *only* a native `bash` way to support the `glob` pattern, you can do that using the [Extended Globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) which is *not* set by default, but can be enabled by

```
shopt -s extglob
```

You have a string defined in the following way

```
myStr=$'apple tree\nbanana tree\norange tree'
```

You can apply the `glob` pattern as follows. Fist read the string into an array, split by the new-line character using `readarray` ( you need to have `bash 4.0` or greater)

```
readarray -t y <<<"$myStr"
```

and now the loop,

```
for i in "${y[@]}"; do 
    [[ $i == @(*n*) ]] && echo "$i" ;
done
```

produces the result as needed.

where, `@(list)` stands for `Matches one of the given patterns`

Another example `glob` to match `*le*` in `apple` (or) `ge` in `orange` would be to use

```
for i in "${y[@]}"; do [[ $i == @(*le*|*ge*) ]] && echo "$i" ; done
apple tree
orange tree
```

for your original input in question,

```
for i in "${y[@]}"; do [[ $i == @(*ban*|*ge*) ]] && echo "$i" ; done
banana tree
orange tree
```

---

For OP's requirement to convert the input arguments to the glob pattetrns, separated by `|` an extra bit of line is required to parse the positional arguments, depending upon the count,

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

myStr=$'apple tree\nbanana tree\norange tree'
readarray -t y <<<"$myStr"

# if the argument count is more than 1, since the input arguments are 
# separated by ' ', replace them with `|` as required in the glob
# pattern

(($# > 1)) && args=$(printf "%s" "$*" | tr ' ' '|') || args="$*"

for i in "${y[@]}"; do
    [[ $i == @($args) ]] && echo "$i" ;
done
```

Now you can just run the script as

```
bash script.sh '*ge*' '*le*'
apple tree
orange tree
```

(or) just one argument,

```
bash script.sh '*ba*'
banana tree
```

Comment: Thankx. however if you don't store the whole input in bash, and process lines one-by-one, your solution can be faster. (e.g. use `while read -r i` instead of `readarray` and `for`).

Comment: In other hand, how can I convert command line arguments (`$@` array) into `$(...|...)` expression?

Comment: Based on your solution and my previous first comment (w/ `read`) I created a better script than your ugly `args` hacking: https://gist.github.com/andras-tim/909aa427343aede851bc6622cf91d628 - However a `grep` with regexp 400x faster than this and yours too. - so mainly I'm finding a "grep like" glob filter?

Comment: @andras.tim: If am not wrong, you asked for native `bash` approach, it is true `bash` is multi-fold slower

Comment: you are right, I was composed too open. My desired solution is a "glob grep", but as far as I know, the `grep` doesn't have globbing mode.

Comment: In other hand, your solution on my steroids is good enough now. But as I said, the `args` hacking and array creating is not acceptable for me. - Please simplify your answer for the newcomers can easily understand the solution. After this I will approve your answer.

Comment: @andras.tim: There is nothing ugly about it as you claim it to be, it has been handled quite safely.

Comment: @andras.tim: And remember your code in its current form is not complete yet. You are not even passing the input yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141562/discussion-between-andras-tim-and-inian).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do what you need :

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
  for pattern in "$@"
  do
    if
      [[ $line = $pattern ]]
    then
      echo "$line"
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

This reads standard input line by line (so would work in "stream-type" applications or very big files).  In Bash conditionals (`[[ ]]`), an equality comparison (as well as `!=`) performs glob-type matching unless the right-hand string is quoted.

Comment: This is looks good, but seems too slow for high amount of paths. I think the native bash implementation will be too slow. E.g. I ran a find on my system, what created output file with 1,2 million paths. The grep w/ regexp completed in 0.061s, however your globbing script ran 43 seconds.

Comment: If your globs just look like `*string*`, then simply replacing `*` with `^.*` or `.*$` may be enough, and that gives you the obvious benefits of `grep` for this kind of application.

Comment: @andras.tim  Please have a look at the other answer I posted, which uses `grep` but translates patterns to regexes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to benefit from the speed of `grep` is to convert patterns to a regular expression.

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
glob_to_regex()
{
  local regex=$1
  regex=${regex//\./\\.}
  regex=${regex/\\/\\\\}
  regex=${regex//\*/.*}
  regex=${regex//\?/.}
  printf %s "^$regex$"
}

regex_from_args()
{
local arg
local not_first=
for arg in "$@"
do
  [[ $not_first ]] && printf %s "|"
  not_first=1
  glob_to_regex "$arg"
done
}

egrep "$(regex_from_args "$@")"
```

Comment: this solution is near hacky... in other hand, works bad when path contains space or special characters (e.g. `[`) - you missed escaping the regex special sequences. I think, this way will be never good if you want to escapes for regex by hand.

Comment: Can you explain why/how that fails with filenames with spaces or special characters?  Or do you mean patters containing these?  It is not clear what you mean by "hacky".  You goal is to perform filtering with globs, and there is no tool (that I know of) that does that directly and fast, and you do not want to use regular expressions instead (which are more widely supported).  There are many constraints to satisfy here...

Comment: Why I think this is hacky: (1) The `$not_first` hack is a bit hacky - why not use concatenate the expression into a variable and strip with `${...%|}`? - (2) I think the most of lines of `glob_to_regex` can be replaced with one `sed`, like `sed 's|\\|\\\\|g;s|\.|\\.|g;s|\*|.*|g;s|\?|.|g'` + use `egrep -x` at and of your script

Comment: Why I think this is not work properly: check `echo -e 'foo[b]ar' | ./filter_script.sh '*o[b]*'`

Comment: My conversion routine does not handle this kind of pattern matching, but you have not been clear what pattern matching language you are expecting to support.  You may want to clarify that.

Comment: As for using variables in programs being a hack, while using a long and difficult to decipher `sed` expressions to perform several replacements as a one-liner being OK, I will say this is a matter of taste at that point.

Comment: ok I accept why you didn't used the `sed`. However when I wrote the **foo[b]ar** I wanted to present a minimal filename and glob pattern example where your code doesn't work. So here is another, more real example `echo '/test/path/new file [10]' | egrep '^.*[10]$'`

Comment: @andras.tim I understand your initial example.  You have not stated in your question the extent of the pattern language you are using, only providing examples with `*` as a globbing pattern.

Comment: Oh, I copied wrong line to the example I wanted to copy `echo '/test/path/new file [10]' | ./filter_script.sh '*[10]'` and yeah, my original example in Q is too light - however I checked the globbing wiki site after your last comment and I want to present an another not working example: `echo '/test/Preices under $1000.txt' | ./filter_script.sh '*under $*'` - so the *glob to regex* translation is not easy, because you should escape lot of valid regex symbols.